# search did not work when enter key is pressed

Tags: opencart

Normally opencart search works when taps the search icon but it didn't work when tapping enter key instead of search icon

here is the code i have tried

```
$('#srch').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            $('.button-search').click();
        }
    });
```

I'm newbie to open cart . Please do the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#header input[name=\'product_search\']').bind('click', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

        if (search) {
            url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
        }

        location = url;
    }

});
```

Try this one.